# How to persist large strings in a POJO?

Tags: java, string, pojo

If I have a property of an object which is a large String (say the contents of a file ~ 50KB to 1 MB, maybe larger), what is the practice around declaring such a property in a POJO? All I need to do is to be able to set a value from one layer of my application and transfer it to another without making the object itself "heavy".

I was considering if it makes sense to associate an InputStream or OutputStream to get / set the value, rather than reference the String itself - which means when I attempt to read the value of the contents, I read it as a stream of bytes, rather than a whole huge string loaded into memory... thoughts?

Comment: How large might the string be? 20k? 20g?

Comment: What do you mean by "persisting in a POJO"? A POJO is a plain old Java object. It lives in memory, and is thus not persistent. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Aaron, JB Nizet: Thanks for helping me improve my question - please check my updates.

Comment: Do you mean that instead of the whole string in the POJO, you want a sort-of-pointer to the string data in database?

Comment: Why are you worried about the object being "heavy"?

Comment: @Neel, you should use the word "persist" to describe storage of data that can be retrieved even if your service is shut down and restarted.

Comment: Even a simple String outside of a POJO is passed essentially as a reference.  When passing a String value to a method, it costs the same whether the String is 1 MB or 10 bytes.  Wrapping that String in a POJO and passing the POJO won't make it more efficient.

Comment: @phatfingers Thanks for correcting me about persistence.

Comment: AbhinavSarkar, phatfingers: Thanks for your comments, please check my updates. Hot Licks: I tried to explain what I mean by "heavy" in my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing depends largely on your anticipated use of the data.  If you're delivering the contents in raw form, then there may be more efficient ways to manage it.

For example, if your app has a web interface, your app may just provide a URL for a web server to stream the contents to the requester.  If it's a CLI-based app, you may be able to get away with a simple file copy.  If your app is processing the file, however, then perhaps your POJO could retain only the results of that processing rather than the raw data itself.

If you wish to provide a general pattern along the lines of using POJO's with references to external streams, I would suggest storing in your POJO something akin to a URI that tells where to find the stream (like a row ID in a database or a filename or a URI) rather than storing an instance of the stream itself.  In doing so, you'll reduce the number of open file handles, prevent potential concurrency issues, and will be able to serialize those objects locally if needed without having to duplicate the raw data persisted elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks phatfingers! In my specific case, I will try to copy the contents of one file into another. Do you think it is a good idea to retain an InputStream as a property, where the InputStream may be built from a URL or a File?

Comment: Use a utility class to provide the InputStream from the URL or filename stored in your POJO.  If you eventually work with multiple threads using that same object, then your POJO will be safe to use and each of your InputStreams will be isolated from one another, and the work of opening, reading, and closing

Comment: (sorry--accidentally entered before finishing) -- If you instantiate, open, and close your stream in a single method call, it's much easier to guarantee that you don't accidentally leave something unfinished.

Answer (score 1):

You could have an object that supplies a stream or an iterator every time you access it. Note that the content has to live on some storage, like a file. I.e your object will store a pointer (e.g. a file path) to the storage and every time someone access it, you open a stream or create an iterator and let that party read. Note also that in order to save on memory, whoever consumes it has to make sure not to store the whole content in memory.

However, 50KB or 1MB is really tiny. Unless you have like gigabytes (or maybe hundred megabytes), I wouldn't try to do something like that.

Also, even if you have large data, it's often simpler to just use files or whatever storage you'll use.

**tl;dr**: Just use String.

Comment: @Neel: Basically I'm trying to tell you that you should just use strings, so.

Comment: Yeah, I got that part - I was trying to request the code snippet for the first part - "object will store a pointer"...